# bitwise AND ini python for comparison

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

```
>>> i=5
>>> i>4 & i<5
True
>>> i>4 and i<5
False
```

I am not able to understand how bitwise AND is used here? The second statement can be understood as 5 is not less than 5, hence it returns false. Can someone throw some light on the first statement?

Comment: This is a precedence issue. (i>4) & (i<5) == False

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit of experimentation in the python shell and i believe that i know what is going on here. I ran:

```py
>>> 5>4 & 5<5
True
>>> 1 & 0
0
>>> True & False
False
>>> (5>4) & (5<5)
False
>>> (5>4 & 5)<5
True
```

So I believe what is happening is it is performing `(5>4 & 5)<5` instead of `(5>4) & (5<5)`

Answer (score 0):

> **&** applies before **>** which applies before **and**

- **a > b and a > c**, it's parsed as **(a > b) and (a > c)**
- **a > b & a > c**, it's parsed as **a > (b & a) > c**